# How does this leetcode solution work? (Finding a single number in an array)

Tags: python, bitwise-xor

**Backstory:**

> So I was on leetcode for the first time and I found an easy problem that seemed interesting and solved it. I was looking at other people's submissions afterward and found this and was blown away. I have a basic understanding of the bitwise xor operator, but I really have no understanding of how this solution works. I would really appreciate a quick summary of what is happening because this seems really interesting.

**Problem:**

`Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.`

`NOTE: Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra 
memory?`

```html
Example 1:
  Input: [2,2,1]
  Output: 1

Example 2:
  Input: [4,1,2,1,2]
  Output: 4
```

**Solution:**

```
def single_number(list):
  result = 0
    for num in list:
      result ^= num
  return result
```

credit to [mack0094](https://leetcode.com/mack0094/) for this solution

Comment: XOR is like a bit flipping mask. For a combination of 1's and 0's.. if you apply it to another combination of 1's and 0's.. everywhere the original number has a bit.. it will flip the bit in the corresponding position of the other number. Applied twice, it flips the bits one way.. then back again to their original state. This is a pretty clever question. Btw, your indentation is off on the solution ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The most important point here is the XOR operator denoted by ^. If we write "result ^= num" this also can be written as "result = result ^ num"

This solution works because we are guaranteed that every element appears twice except 1 of the elements.

Using XOR, any time we XOR a number twice by the same number, we get the same original number. For example: 4 ^ 1 = 5 and 5 ^ 1 = 4. Another way to say this is:
4 ^ 1 ^ 1 = 4.

Note also any number XOR 0 is the number itself, example: 0 ^ 5 = 5

We loop through all the elements in the list. Let's see what happens with the input [2, 2, 1]:

```
def single_number(list):
    result = 0
    for num in list:
      result ^= num
      print(result)
    return result
```

The print statement will yield:

```
2
0
1

Result starts as 0.
1st iteration: result = result ^ num = 0 ^ 2 = 2
2nd iteration: result = result ^ num = 2 ^ 2 = 0
3rd iteration: result = result ^ num = 0 ^ 1 = 1
```

You have to get down XOR logic first. Then convince yourself if a number appears twice it'll get the single digit number back to its original form. Another example:

```
[2, 3, 4, 3, 4]
2 ^ 3 = 1
1 ^ 4 = 5
5 ^ 3 = 6
6 ^ 4 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

first, we have two facts about the xor operator:

- `x xor x = 0`
- xor is commutative and associative. this effectively allows us to reorder the input sequence to our convenience, and we know that the result will be the same.

---

to see why the algorithm works – group the input sequence into pairs.

for example: we can write a sample input sequence as `(a xor a) xor (b xor b) xor (c xor c) xor d`. the input sequence doesn’t *have* to be in this form, but ***we can always rearrrange it***.

notice that each pair evaluates to 0, and the result of `0 xor d = d`, which is the number we want to find.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Explanation

If we `Xor` any `even` number of identical numbers the result will be zero. As long as there is one value that doesn't have an identical pair we will have a value that is not 0.

The `Xor` converts to binary and compares 2 bits. if the bits are the same the result is 0, else 1. Doing this constructs a new number.

**Below is a table:**

```
  0111
^ 1010
======
  1101 = 13
```

If we compare 2 numbers that are the same then the resulting number is 0. When we compare a number to 0 the resulting number is the compared number. 2 ^ 0 = 2. Because no bits line up. Therefore a list constructed of the following numbers will also work `[2,2,2,1,1,1,1]` The 1's cancel themselves out and the first 2's cancel themselves. All that's left is a single 2. Hope this makes sence.